# How do I deserialize each element of a json array into their proper subclasses based on one of the element's values? (C#)

Tags: c#, json

Is this even possible? I've been trying for quite a while and can't figure it out, and can't really find any videos or anything on how to do it.

Here's the scripts I used:

cs script `Test`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public abstract class Test {
    public static Dictionary<string, Test> tests = JsonToTests();

    public string type { get; }
    public string stringId { get; }
    public string[] array { get; }
    public byte ebyte { get; }
    public short eshort { get; }
    public bool ebool { get; }
    public (byte, byte) tuple { get; }

    public static Dictionary<string, Test> JsonToTests() {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/test.json");
        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);
        JObject[] jsonObjects = jsonArray.Cast<JObject>().ToArray();

        Dictionary<string, Test> returnData = new Dictionary<string, Test>();
        foreach (JObject jsonObject in jsonObjects) {
            string id   = jsonObject.Value<string>("stringId");
            Debug.Log("id: " + id);
            string type = jsonObject.Value<string>("type");
            Test test = null;

            switch (type) {
                case "plus":
                    test = jsonObject.ToObject<TestPlus>();
                break;
                case "plusplus":
                    test = jsonObject.ToObject<TestPlusPlus>();
                break;
                case "plusplusplus":
                    test = jsonObject.ToObject<TestPlusPlusPlus>();
                break;
            }

            if (test == null) {
                Debug.LogError("the json is invalid or something");
            } else {
                returnData.Add(id, test);
            }
        }
        return returnData;
    }
}

public class TestPlus : Test {
    public string valuePlus { get; }
}

public class TestPlusPlus : Test {
    public string valuePlusPlus { get; }
}

public class TestPlusPlusPlus : Test {
    public string valuePlusPlusPlus { get; }
}
```

json script `test`:

```
[
  {
    "type": "plus",
    "stringId": "string!",
    "array":  [ 1, 1, 1],
    "ebyte":   255,
    "eshort":  256,
    "ebool":   true,
    "tuple": [ 2, 2 ],
    "valuePlus": "hello"
  },
  {
    "type": "plusplus",
    "stringId": "string!2",
    "array":  [ 1, 1, 1],
    "ebyte":   255,
    "eshort":  256,
    "ebool":   true,
    "tuple": [ 2, 2 ],
    "valuePlusPlus": "string!!!!!1"
  },
  {
    "type": "plusplusplus",
    "stringId": "string!3",
    "array":  [ 1, 1, 1],
    "ebyte":   255,
    "eshort":  256,
    "ebool":   true,
    "tuple": [ 2, 2 ],
    "valuePlusPlusPlus": "string!!!!!2"
  }
]
```

cs script `BasicScript`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BasicScript : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        Debug.Log(         (Test.tests["string!"] as TestPlus).valuePlus);
        Debug.Log(    (Test.tests["string!2"] as TestPlusPlus).valuePlusPlus);
        Debug.Log((Test.tests["string!3"] as TestPlusPlusPlus).valuePlusPlusPlus);
    }
}
```

While running `BasicScript` all I get is 3 null values every frame, instead of the expected ones.
The logs from the `Test` script however, are the expected values. I know—or am pretty sure—I can just get the values like I did those ones, but I'd prefer if it dynamically? added new fields I put into them.

Comment: At this point I've kinda convinced myself that my "non-preferred" way (`string value = jsonObject.Value<string>("value");`) would be better, but it would still be nice to know how to solve this problem that's bested me or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not deserialize to c# class if class doesn't allow to set properties. You have to use init at least. Also tuple is not deserialized too. After fixing, this code works

```
List<Test> tests = JArray.Parse(json).Select(ja => (Test) (((string) ja["type"]) =="plus"
                                                 ? ja.ToObject<TestPlus>()
                                                 : (string) ja["type"]=="plusplus"
                                                 ? ja.ToObject<TestPlusPlus>()
                                                 : ja.ToObject<TestPlusPlusPlus>())).ToList();

public abstract class Test
{
    public string type { get; init;}
    public string stringId { get; init; }
    public string[] array { get; init;}
    public byte ebyte { get; init;}
    public short eshort { get; init; }
    public bool ebool { get; init;}
    public byte[] tuple { get; init; }
}

public class TestPlus : Test
{
    public string valuePlus { get; init;}
}

public class TestPlusPlus : Test
{
    public string valuePlusPlus { get; init;}
}

public class TestPlusPlusPlus : Test
{
    public string valuePlusPlusPlus { get; init;}
}
```

UPDATE

init works only with c# 9+. Otherwise you can add [JsonProperty] attribute and private set for example

```
public abstract class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty("stringId")]
    public string stringId { get; private set; }
    // ... other properties
}
```

but if you change the class names or just change "type" property of json string according to a class name, the code would be much more simple

```
List<Test> tests = JArray.Parse(json)
                         .Select(ja => (Test) ja.ToObject(Type
                         .GetType((string)ja["type"])))
                         .ToList();
    
}

public abstract class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; private set; }

    // or maybe better
    //public string type { get {return this.GetType().Name; } }

    [JsonProperty("stringId")]
    public string stringId { get; private set; }
    public string[] array { get; init;}
    public byte ebyte { get; init;}
    public short eshort { get; init; }
    public bool ebool { get; init;}
    public byte[] tuple { get; init; }
}

public class plus : Test
{
    public string valuePlus { get; init;}
}

public class plusplus : Test
{
    public string valuePlusPlus { get; init;}
}

public class plusplusplus : Test
{
    public string valuePlusPlusPlus { get; init;}
}
```

Comment: Using init gives me errors. What `using` statements are are you using? (It does work with `set;`, but init would be better)

Comment: @freddyfearful init works with c# 9+